# I want to loop though each sub-directories & check if *.v or *.sv file is present or not , if it is present then do some operation using csh script?

Tags: linux, csh

NOTE : I have made an attempt to implement this below logic for each sub-directories. But not able to do so.

```
#!/bin/csh -f
 
setenv option $<
switch ($option)
cd $option
foreach i (`ls`)
pushd $i
foreach j (`ls *.v *.sv`)
#sed -nE 's/^module +([^ (#]+) *[#(].*$/\1/p' $j > mod_name.txt
awk -F'[ \t#(;]+' '/^module/{ print $2}' $j > mod_name.txt
foreach k (`cat mod_name.txt`)
sed -r -i "s/^[ ]*$k/${k}_ext/g" $j
end
end
popd
end
```

Here I will pass parent directory name only and, then my script would loop through each subdirectories and check for *.v & *.sv file to do some operation and check for further directories so on.

pv_ncvlog is a parent directory name.
For Example :

```
**cd pv_ncvlog**/


SKIP_lna64    bin.hppa/     bin.lnppc/    bin.sun4/     bin/          etc/          lost+found/   test/         
SKIP_lnppc    bin.ibmrs/    bin.lnx86/    bin.sun4v/    customer_lib/ ict/          rd_inca_test/ vplan/        
bin.all/      bin.lna64/    bin.sol86@    bin.wint/     docs/         ifcs/         stream_mgmt/
```

Comment: Does it have to be csh? Would you accept a bash solution? I would base a bash solution on `find -type d` to generate a list of subdirectories, then not use `ls` but simple shell wildcards to process *.v and *.sv files.

Comment: ok , go ahead. I will try to emulate it in csh. I need logic .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution using bash. In case you want Bourne Shell, use `for file in $dir/*.v $dir/*.sv`:

```
for dir in $(find . -type d)  # generate all subdirectories
do 
    for file in $dir/*.{v,sv} # generate names of all .v and .sv files
    do 
        # The if below is required because a literal 
        # DIRECTORYNAME/*.{v,sv} will be generated  
        # as $file if there is no file that matches 
        # the wildcard
        if [ -f $file ]        
        then echo $file       # replace this with your awk code
        fi
    done
done
```

Note that `find` generates all directories in the current tree. If you only want the first level of directories, add `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). I don't know `csh` but I suspect the OP's code where `foreach` reads from `ls` is also flawed; probably flawed somewhat differently, [but still](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Yes, `ls` is problematic. In any case, using the shell's wildcard feature is simpler and more elegant. Why complicate things? Like you, I don't know how csh treats wildcards, and a semi-famous article is floating around that makes the point that csh is a crappy programming language. Search for *csh considered harmful*.

Comment: My main point is you start with `for dir in $(find . -type d)` and it's flawed. The rest of my comment only indicates the original code is probably also flawed, so you did not make it worse. Still your code is flawed by itself.

Comment: Thanks all. I have written a code in csh , to suit's my purpose. And I have used ls as ......foreach i ( `ls *.v  *.sv ` )